# Signing file with detached signature

Tags: c#, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

I'm trying to make detached signature for doc, xml etc. files. I was started at example from Microsoft website ([example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml(v=vs.90).aspx)). But even that simple example isn't working for me. Every time I get "Can not recognize the URI...". I was also tryied to set reference to @"file://c://1.xml" etc. but no success.

Comment: At which line ? MSDN examples are not standalone files you can copy and run, for this you have to use [sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a security update in March 2016, external signatures are disabled by default.

You can enable it by setting a registry value:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Security@SignedXmlAllowDetachedSignature=1
```

See more in [MS Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3148821)

Comment: I have another problem with setting URI with only file name (without absolute path). The same problem is described here http://stackoverflow.com/users/1488453/user1488453. Did anybody solved this .problem?